# Change login error messages? Cookie error message

Tags: customization

I have tried searching for this, and I have found it is possible to change the login error messages using a hook. But I cannot find how to change this error message:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Which appears if cookies are disabled and you try to login. How do I customize this text?

Thank you!

Comment: This message is coded in wp-login.php but is not filterable. Though it is of course translatable via gettext, so maybe you could take advantage of this as a possible way to customize it.

Comment: @Iceable gettext is filterable, so you can use that filter and modify this text.

Answer (score 1):

This text is hardcoded in `wp-login.php` file (line 886):

```
$user = new WP_Error( 'test_cookie', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must <a href="%s">enable cookies</a> to use WordPress.' ),
                __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Cookies' ) ) );
```

and as you can see, there is no filter used to generate it... Almost no filter. Why almost? Because it is translated and that means that you can use `gettext` filter to modify it.

```
function my_change_cookies_disabled_error( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    $default = '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must <a href="%s">enable cookies</a> to use WordPress.';

    if ( $translated_text == $default ) {
        $translated_text = __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: My error message', 'my_text_domain' );
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_change_cookies_disabled_error', 20, 3 );
```